# $f(x)=x^2+y^2+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

I've been stuck on this problem for a while. If it is reducible, then $f=gh$, where $g,h$ are of degree $1$ (they cannot be of degree $0$, since constant terms are units). Then when considered as elements of $\mathbb{C}[x][y]$,
$$g(y)=a_0(x)+a_1(x)y$$
$$h(y)=b_0(x)+b_1(x)y$$
where $a_0(x),a_1(x),b_0(x),b_1(x)$ are only dependent on $x$. Thus,
$$x^2+y^2+1=gh=(a_0(x)+a_1(x)y)(b_0(x)+b_1(x)y)$$
This implies that $a_1(x)$ and $b_1(x)$ cannot involve $x$, since their product is $1$. Thus,
$$x^2+y^2+1=gh=(a_0(x)+a_1y)(b_0(x)+b_1y)$$
for some $a_1, b_1 \in \mathbb{C}$. But I do not know what to do next.

Comment: Maybe somehow there is a way to show that $a_1, b_1$ have to be $1$?

Comment: For any integral domain $R$, the degree function from $R[x]\to \Bbb N$ is additive. in the sense that $deg(fg)=deg(f)+deg(g)$. Now use this when $R=\Bbb C[x]$ and similarly with $R=\Bbb C[y]$

Comment: @PVAL , would you mind expanding on that? I know this property but I have a hard time applying it...

Comment: A generalization is discussed here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/486668/x2-y2-z2-is-irreducible-in-mathbb-c-x-y-z

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a_0(x)b_0(x)=x^2+1$ so, up to bringing a constant on one side and switching names, either of these holds:

1. $a_0(x)=x^2+1$ and $b_0(x)=1$. But then you'd have $0=a_0(x)b_1+b_0(x)a_1=b_1(x^2+1)+a_1$, which is impossible for $b_1\ne0$
2. $a_0(x)=x+i$ and $b_0(x)=x-i$. But then you'd have $b_1(x+i)+a_1(x-i)=0$ which does not leave much choice for $a_1$ and $b_1$...

Comment: Thus, $b_1+a_1=0 \implies b_1=-a_1$, so they have to be additive inverses of each other. But we also know that $b_1a_1=1$, so $$b_1(-b_1)=1$$ Thus, $b_1^2=-1$, implying that $b_1=\pm i$. Similarly, $a_1= \pm i$. Thus, I just need to check that none of these options will yield a correct factorization?

Comment: I would have gone $b_1i-a_1i=0$ instead of the product.

Comment: Thus, $b_1+b_1=0$ implying that $b_1=0$, a contradiction. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

**Geometric Solution**

Consider the homogeneous polynomial $F(x,y,z):=x^2+y^2+z^2$ in $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$.  Then, $F$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{C}$ if and only if $F$, $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$, $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$, and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}$ have no nonzero common root (i.e., they have no common root in $\mathbb{CP}^2$).  As the only common root of $x^2+y^2+z^2$, $2x$, $2y$, and $2z$ is $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$, we conclude that $F$ is indeed irreducible.  Hence, $f(x,y):=F(x,y,1)$ is also irreducible.

---

**Solution with Eisenstein's Criterion**

Prove that $y^2+1$ has no repeated prime factor in $\mathbb{C}[y]$.  Then, consider $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2+1$ as an element of $\big(\mathbb{C}[y]\big)[x]$.  Apply Eisenstein's Criterion with respect to one of the irreducible factors of $y^2+1$.

Answer (score 4):

Continuing from where you stopped:
$$
a_0(x)b_0(x)+(a_0(x)b_1(x)+a_1(x)b_0(x))+a_1(x)b_1(x)y^2=x^2+y^2+1
$$
tells you that
$$
a_1(x)b_1(x)=1
$$
so they're constant and inverse of one another. Hence it's not restrictive to assume they're $1$. Therefore $b_0(x)=-a_0(x)$ and finally
$$
-a_0(x)^2=x^2+1
$$
which is impossible, because $x^2+1=(x+i)(x-i)$ has no repeated factor in $\mathbb{C}[x]$.