# Pseudo algebraically closed fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-geometry

i am reading Fried-Jarden's book *Field Arithmetic* and I have a question on Pseudo Algebraically closed (PAC) fields.

We say that a field $K$ is PAC if every variety absolutely irreducible over $K$ has a $K$-rational point. Recall that a variety is absolutely irreducible if it is irreducible over $\overline{K}$, and a $K$-rational point is an element on the variety with all its coordinates in $K$.

My question is the following: Is $\mathbb{Q}$ a PAC field? And more generally, is any number field PAC?

My attempt: I would like to find a polynomial in two variables with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$ which is irreducible over $\mathbb{C}$ and that does not have any root in $\mathbb{Q}^2$. This would show that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not PAC, which is my guess, but so far i've been unable to find this example.

I am also guessing that, more generally, every number field is not PAC, although this question is much more difficult...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1885165/fx-x2y21-is-irreducible-in-mathbbcx-y

Answer (score 3):

I think that the projective conic with equation
$$X^2+Y^2+Z^2=0$$
is absolutely irreducible over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: But it has a root in $\mathbb{Q}^3$, the $(0,0,0)$. I found $x^2+y^2+1$. This works to prove that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not PAC.

Comment: It has no point in $\mathbb P^2(\Bbb Q)$. @El.Gon.Zalo