# $x^a+ y^b + z^c$ is irreducible in $\mathbb C[x,y,z]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, complex-numbers, irreducible-polynomials, multivariate-polynomial

> Let $a,b,c$ be positive integers. Then $f = x^a + y^b + z^c$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$.

By Gauss, $f$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$ iff is so in $\mathbb{C}(z)[x,y]$, and so iff in $\mathbb{C}(y, z)[x]$.

> So by Eisenstein, it is sufficient to show that $y^b + z^c$ has a single prime factor.

If $b=c$, this factors through $\Pi(y + \zeta ^i z)$ for some primitive root of unity $\zeta$, so ok.

> But if $b\neq c$?

This question is related to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/486668/x2-y2-z2-is-irreducible-in-mathbb-c-x-y-z?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Thank you very much!

Comment: $y^2+z^4=(y+iz^2)(y-iz^2)$, so your guess isn't quite right. You'll need to look at something more number-theoretic than just equality of $b$ and $c$...

Comment: If $b\mid c$ you can factor as $\prod (y+\zeta^iz^{c/b})$ and likewise for $c\mid b.$

Comment: More generally $y^b+z^c$ is reducible if $b$ and $c$ share a common factor; if $d=\gcd(b,c)$ then
$$y^b+z^c=(y^{b/d})^d+(z^{c/d})^d,$$
which factors as a product of homogenized cyclotomic polynomials.

Comment: So can you prove that it is irreducible if $a,b$ relatively prime?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. So I want to show: $y^b + z^c$ has no multiple prime factors.

Comment: @agababibu It suffices to show that there is at least one irreducible prime factor with multiplicity $1$.

Comment: @Servaes You're right. It's my mistake.

Comment: The phrase *"...it is sufficient to show that $y^b+z^c$ has a single prime factor."* is not exactly what you mean; instead it is sufficient that it has an irreducible factor with multiplicity $1$. Or equivalently, that there exists a nonconstant $f\in\Bbb{C}[y,z]$ such that $f$ divides $y^b+z^c$ but $f^2$ does not.

Comment: @Servaes Polynomials is a generic tag. Multivariate-polynomials is a kind of subtag, not used often btw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f\in\Bbb{C}[y,z]$ be a factor of $y^b+z^c$ with multiplicity $m\geq1$, and let $g\in\Bbb{C}[y,z]$ be such that $y^b+z^c=f^mg$. Then taking derivatives with respect to $y$ and $z$ shows that
$$by^{b-1}=mf^{m-1}f_yg+g_yf^m=f^{m-1}(mgf_y+g_yf),$$
$$cz^{c-1}=mf^{m-1}f_zg+g_zf^m=f^{m-1}(mgf_z+g_zf).$$
In particular we see that $f^{m-1}$ divides both $by^{b-1}$ and $cz^{c-1}$, and hence it is a constant. This shows that $y^b+z^c$ has no repeated irreducible factors. Hence by Eisensteins criterion, the polynomial
$$x^a+y^b+z^c\in\Bbb{C}[y,z][x],$$
is irreducible as it is Eisenstein w.r.t. every irreducible factor of $y^b+z^c$.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!