# Fermat-like polynomials are irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I am attempting to prove the following result.

> Let $K$ be a field, $n \ge 3$, and $e_1,\ldots, e_n$ be positive integers which are not multiples of the characteristic. Then the polynomial
> $$
> p(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^{e_i}
> $$
> is irreducible in $K[x_1,\ldots, x_n]$.

I am attempting to expand the outline given in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/487361) into a proof. My attempt to do so is below.

> Proof by induction.
>
> For the base case, $n = 3$, we claim that irreducibility of $x^l + y^m + z^n$ in $k[x,y,z]$ is equivalent to irreducibility in $k(z)[x,y]$. Since the coefficients of our polynomial are all $1$, this follows from Gauss' Lemma; in particular, both are equivalent to irreducibility in $k(y,z)[x]$.
>
> So we view our polynomial as $x^l + (y^m + z^n)$ in $k(z)[y][x]$ and want to satisfy Eisenstein's criterion. In particular, we can check by the derivative test that $a_0 \equiv (y^m + z^n)$ in $k(z)[y]$ is separable, since it is of the form $y^m + c$ for $c\neq 0$ and the characteristic does not divide $m$. Since $a_0$ is separable, its prime factors in $k(z)[y]$ are all distinct. Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be the prime ideal generated by one of these prime factors. The conditions of Eisenstein are satisfied, so our polynomial is irreducible in $k(z)[y][x]$ and in $k[x,y,z]$.
>
> Now for the inductive step, also by Eisenstein. We write
> $$
>    p(x) = x_n^{e_n} + (x_1^{e_1} + \cdots + x_{n-1}^{e_{n-1}}) \in k[x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1}][x_n].
> $$
> Since by the inductive hypothesis the constant term is irreducible, it generates a prime ideal $(x_1^{e_1} + \cdots + x_{n-1}^{e_{n-1}})$ in the polynomial ring. We need to check that
> $$
>     x_1^{e_1} + \cdots + x_{n-1}^{e_{n-1}} \not\in \langle x_1^{e_1} + \cdots + x_{n-1}^{e_{n-1}}\rangle^2 = \langle(x_1^{e_1} + \cdots + x_{n-1}^{e_{n-1}})^2\rangle.
> $$
> (Hagen von Eitzen) If it were, then setting $x_2,\ldots, x_{n-1}$ all to zero gives
> $$
>    x_1^{e_1} = x_1^{2e_1} f(x_1)
> $$
> for some $f \in k[x_1]$, which is absurd. Hence the inductive step holds by Eisenstein.

1. (Edit: Answered by Hagen von Eitzen) This last fact seems like it should be true, at least in characteristic not 2, but I don't see how to prove it. Or do I need another technique to do the inductive step?
2. This proof does not use the full strength of the assumptions, as far as I can see. I have so far only needed *one* of the $e_i$ to not be multiples of the characteristic. Am I making a mistake in the base case, or is the statement true that generally?

Comment: Does this not also hold for $n=2$?

Comment: $x^2 + y^2 = (x+iy)(x-iy)$ over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: *facepalm*, and of course $x^3+y^3=(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)$ over any field ...

Comment: Let $x,y,z,w_1,w_2,\dots,w_N$ be variables, $K$ a field, $e,f,g>0$ some integers, $e$ being not zero modulo the characteristic of $K$, and $p$ a polynomial in the polynomial ring $R=K[x,y,z,w_1,w_2,\dots,w_N]$ of the shape $$p = p(x,y,z,w_1,w_2,\dots,w_N) \in x^e + y^f + z^g + (w_1,w_2,\dots,w_M)\ .$$ Then a (non-trivial) factor decomposition $p=qr$ in $R$ "must split" $x^e$ in pieces in the factors. (I.e. the "$x$-degrees" of $q,r$ seen in $K[\dots][x]$ are both $<e$.) And also $y^f$, and $z^g$. So we obtain a factorization of $x^e+y^f+z^g=p(x,y,z,0,0,\dots,0)$. No induction is needed.

Comment: That's a nice trick to avoid the induction, thanks! So the statement is true under the weaker assumptions -- only a single exponent has to be nonzero modulo the characteristic.

Answer (score 2):

Ad 1: If $x_1^{e_1}+\cdots x_n^{e_n}=(x_1^{e_1}+\cdots +x_n^{e_n})^2f(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$, then $x_1^{e_1}=x_1^{2e_1}f(x_1,0,\ldots,0)$ in $k[x_1]$, which is absurd for $e_1>0$ in all characteristics.

Comment: Ah, excellent, thank you.